# How can I plot a pattern of random points in a specific region?

Tags: matlab, plot

I wrote this matlab code to plot a set of random points in a specific region of the graph. I need to set the `xlim` and `ylim` in the range `(1,512) (-1,512)` but when I substituted this values in the following code nothing is plotted.I tried also to insert the range `150,350` that represent the central part of the graph in which I want to plot all points. How can I fix the problem?

```
x = rand(1, 50);
y = rand(1, 50);
plot(x,y,'.')
xlim([-0.2 1.2])
ylim([-0.2 1.2])
```

Comment: `rand` generates random numbers within (0,1).

Answer (score 2):

The output of `rand` is going to contain values between `0` and `1` so when you expand the x and y limits to `[1 512]` all data is going to be shown within *the lower 1/512th of the axes* and therefore you can't see the individual points.

If you want your random values to actually span the range `[1 512]` (for `x`) and `[-1 512]` (for `y`), then you'll want to alter the output of `rand` accordingly.

```
x = 1 + rand(1, 50) * 511;
y = rand(1, 50) * 513 - 1;

plot(x, y, '.')

xlim([1 512]);
ylim([-1 512]);
```

[image]

A more general solution would be to create an anonymous function which creates random numbers within the specified range

```
myrand = @(r, varargin)rand(varargin{:}) * diff(r) + min(r);

xrange = [1 512];
yrange = [-1 512];
x = myrand(xrange, 1, 50);
y = myrand(yrange, 1, 50);

plot(x, y, '.')

xlim(xrange);
ylim(yrange);
```

Or if you want your points to be within a certain region inside of the axes

```
x = myrand([50 100], 1, 50);
y = myrand([50 100], 1, 50);

plot(x, y, '.');

xlim([0 150])
ylim([0 150])
```

Comment: Thank you Suever, I used this notation too but I want tho have my random point focused only in the central part of the graph (I mean between (150-350) both for  x and y axes) and not at the outer boundaries.

Comment: @Jiu Then change your axes limits to that.

Comment: @Jiu Yes it is the upper and lower limits of the random numbers that you would like to generate